# Name of property where density function after thermal expansion is related to the one before

Tags: mathematics, density

I have a one dimensional rod of non uniform density $\mu(x)$ and length $l$, upon heating, it expands into a rod of length $l'$. Under heating, the density function may change form to some other expression.. what would be the name of the property if I could write this new density function $\mu'$ as the old density function composed with **some function** which maps points along the length of the original rod to the expanded rod (g(x) )? i.e:

$$ \mu' = \mu \circ g(x)$$

The following chart may help clear my question:

$$ \mu: \text{length across non expanded rod} \to \text{ density along non expanded rod} $$

$$ \mu': \text{length across non expanded rod}(x) \to \text{length across expanded rod} ;g(x) \to \mu \circ g(x)= \text{ density along expanded rod}$$

Is there name for an assumption that such a $g$ exists?

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236383/could-somebody-explain-why-exactly-is-the-density-of-the-lower-rod-is-equal-to?noredirect=1#comment8803502_4236383)

Comment: I just realized I answered that math question, and also that you were the one who asked the question on MSE to which I linked in my answer. As I explained in my answer (and as @Jake Mirra writes below), dropping the Jacobian factor is just plain wrong, and the Youtube video is wrong in its assertion of "same density different lengths".

Comment: My question is not about the jacobian factor.. even you had used a similar assumption in your MSE answer @peek-a-boo

Answer (score 2):

Without a Jacobian factor, this is a rather strange, and I would argue meaningless, relation.  Dropping the physical context and speaking purely mathematically, you seem to be asking when a function $\mu$ has a right inverse.  For that, it needs to be surjective...

Comment: Have you checked the linked post :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236383/could-somebody-explain-why-exactly-is-the-density-of-the-lower-rod-is-equal-to?noredirect=1#comment8803502_4236383

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to explain the result in the video mathematically